# py2exe not working, libvorbisfile-3.dll is not found

Tags: python, py2exe

I'm making a small pygame project and I want my friends to play it without installing python. I heard that py2exe compiles python so other people can play so I tried it,

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['Code.py'])
```

I ran this setup.py script with cmd and it worked! But when I tried to run the executable file it came up with

```
pygame.error: Failed loading libvorbisfile-3.dll: The specified module could not be found.
```

I tried importing pygame into the setup.py script but the error still comes up. I need some help.

Comment: Did the .exe appear in a folder called `dist`? And were there any .dlls in that folder? Py2exe is designed to let you share Python programs with those who haven't installed Python, but the .exe may still require some .dlls...